# Show div during page refresh or user clicks link

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax

(First of all, I use WordPress) I have a loader when the page is loaded, it only appears when the current page is loaded.
I would like to show this loader as soon as the page starts refreshing to go to another page, when the user clicks on a link.

I've tried using onClick, Ajax ... Nothing works, my page loads blank in some parts of the site.

Does anyone know something that works to display a div when clicking a link? Assuming the page loader has a class="loftloaderspiner"

Comment: A blank page is not the same page that you clicked the link on and all the code from that one is gone. When you get a  blank page inspect the generated source. There are numerous solutions all over the web for wordpress blank page

Answer (score 0):

When you "click a link" - you can do anything you want. You can prevent the default behavior - and instead 'do something' - and then after - make a request to that URL / but - in your case - it's still going to connect to the server + build and HTML page from PHP on the server + send back a reference to that HTML page + build the DOM + paint the page... etc / and it's not going to be smooth.

You can totally - go and 'fetch'(ajax) - new content for the page - and then rebuild part of the page / clien-side rendered --- BUT then what about making sure the URL changes... and the back button works... etc..

I feel your pain - and I understand your desire to do this. This same thing is basically why I became a web developer - BUT - in the end... it's just better to *let it go*.

Choose to make an interconnected set of web documents (a website) - and just deal with it's constraints and benefits for what they are ---

OR - build a web application - and use adult tools like Ember.js - and go all in.

A third option... would depend on your goals... and the project. If you need some fancy stuff - but it's not URL / router based - then you can plop a little Vue.js (or just JavaScrip) app in the middle of your PHP page.

But - all of these options sound a little out of your skill-level so far (which is OK!) - but / my suggestion - is to not get hung up on loaders. In they end... the user doesn't care / and they are super super hard to do well - and in the end - they're super expensive for very little return.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for everything. I am writing a progressive web app with WordPress, it's because of this I need to create this experience, cause app stores like Play Store and Apple Store recommend to show that there's something loading for immersive experiences.

Comment: do you know an way to install this frameworks in WordPress?

Comment: I don't know how to explain it. I've done some stuff like that... but it was like 50k worth of work... so, again... I don't recommend it - unless it has real - MEASURABLE reasons for the user experience. https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/07/improving-user-flow-through-page-transitions/ or https://css-tricks.com/page-transitions-for-everyone/ or get a WP theme with that stuff built in